# Как узнать все об области видимости класса с помощью рефлексии в C#?

Tags: c#, доступ, рефлексия, область-видимости

Необходимо узнать модификаторы доступа определенного класса,используя методы рефлексии.

Comment: Это разве не то что Вам нужно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426134/reflection-and-access-modifiers-on-a-property

Comment: Да, это помогло, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = typeof(TestClass).Attributes;
```